# turtlebot sim crashes on subscribing to any topic

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First I run the turtlebot run launch file from the terminal:

```
    $ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

Then in a new terminal:

```
     $ rostopic echo /scan
```

As soon as I subscribe to the /scan topic i get the following  error:

```
gzserver: /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreRenderSystem.cpp:546: virtual void Ogre::RenderSystem::setDepthBufferFor(Ogre::RenderTarget*): Assertion `bAttached && "A new DepthBuffer for a RenderTarget was created, but after creation" "it says it's incompatible with that RT"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 21624, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/pranav/.ros/log/f18cc0fc-ccc2-11e7-9a30-9cb6d0e527e7/gazebo-1.log].
```

log file: /home/pranav/.ros/log/f18cc0fc-ccc2-11e7-9a30-9cb6d0e527e7/gazebo-1*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276241/turtlebot-sim-crashes-on-subscribing-to-any-topic/) by [inani47](https://answers.ros.org/users/32531/inani47/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monabf](https://answers.ros.org/users/33046/monabf/) on 2018-01-25**:
Hi @inani47, did you manage to fix that ? I am having the same issue of gazebo crashing with no reason when launching it with ros and this version of Ogre.

**Comment by [inani47](https://answers.ros.org/users/32531/inani47/) on 2018-04-08**:
@monabf sorry for the late reply. I was able to resolve the issue by updating to a newer version of Gazebo. All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand - I also got around this by updating to a newer version of Gazebo (I'm running Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04).

I followed the "Alternative Installation" instructions here (with an important exception noted below):
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu

IMPORTANT NOTE - if you're on Kinetic, you want to install "gazebo7" NOT "gazebo9" (which would be for Melodic)

Hope that helps - I spent many hours on Google figuring this out. But now the examples in Chapter 7 of Programming Robots with ROS run (as far as I've tried).

Cheers,
/K

---

Originally posted by [KFW](https://answers.ros.org/users/31239/kfw/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0